# Getting coordinates of robot positions from move_base

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm playing around `move_base` , trying to find a way to get the coordinations of my robot each time it moves on the map ( **x,y, rotation** ).
Any idea how to get theses from the `move_base`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377610/getting-coordinates-of-robot-positions-from-move_base/) by [anonymous72456](https://answers.ros.org/users/72456/anonymous72456/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`move_base` uses a global costmap and a local costmap.

You can get the pose of the bot in the `global_frame` of the costmap using the [costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS::getRobotPose()](http://docs.ros.org/en/jade/api/costmap_2d/html/classcostmap__2d_1_1Costmap2DROS.html#a19db98a31b461e1742a7776b8016e7cf) function.

---

Originally posted by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) with karma: 310 on 2021-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous72456](https://answers.ros.org/users/72456/anonymous72456/) on 2021-05-04**:
thanks for the answer, but i need the return as a value not boolean.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-05-04**:
Let's assume that `move_base` uses  `costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* global_costmap`.

Then, we can use the following -

```
tf::Stamped< tf::Pose > global_pose;

bool flag = global_costmap->getRobotPose(global_pose);
```

Does that make sense?